# Product view page scrolls up randomly on mobile device

Tags: magento2, product

In the product view page when I scroll down a little bit, sometimes (very often) the page scrolls to the top.

This is the effect of the scroll up:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKwLVwIMrpM

Comment: Can you reproduce it in Chrome, simulating a mobile view? Are there any hints about what's happening in the developer console of Chrome?

Comment: no, I can't reproduce it in desktop chrome simulating a mobile device, it behaves normally, I don't know whether it happens also on a real apple device but I tried both Xiaomi and Samsung physical phone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was on the top of the two element of the fotorama widget:
.fotorama__active
.fotorama__img

They have top: 0 and position: absolute, so when chrome topbar shows/hides, the page suddenly jumps to the top.

I solved the problem extending the following css:

```
@media @mobile {
        .catalog-product-view {
            .fotorama__stage__frame.fotorama__active {
                position: static !important;
            }
            .fotorama__stage__frame .fotorama__img {
                position: static !important;
                transform: initial !important;
            }
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although above answer works perfectly fine, still curious to see if it can be done with anything transformation related css on gallery.css.

Seems to be default issue of fotorama library. Just got to know that this will be fixed on next release as per [this](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/25385).